# Recursively generate 3-regular planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, recursion, planar-graphs

I'm trying to prove that there are an unbounded number of (non-isomorphic) 3-regular planar graphs with faces of degree 3 or 6. I know that there are only 4 faces of degree 3 in such a graph. I cannot find a way to recursively generate such graphs, however. I have looked at some examples but was unable to find any recurring pattern.

Answer (score 4):

One recursive construction is to take a picture like the following, with a triangle surrounded by "layers" of hexagons:

[image]

Then, put four of these pictures together as the sides of a tetrahedron.

Comment: But don't the 2 vertices near each corner of the largest triangle only have degree 2?

Comment: The outer infinite face doesn't have degree 3 or 6 either

Comment: Read my last sentence again! This is not the whole graph, you put four of them together, joining them along the sides.